# Localise values from sqllite android database

Tags: android, sqlite, localization

I have a problem. I making android application. I use REST server to get data and put data back. I don't know how to parse data from rest in specific language in android application. I know that android have a res files to resource values to show interface in user language, but how to use that res files to translate values from REST response or SQLlite records which must to be translate to user language. I this get from server database, like this picture:[image: This image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve a problem. I want to share with you, maybe someone had a same problem.First I get data from android database(populate it with data from json data from REST):

```
 public List<String> getAllInList(){
    List<String> labels = new ArrayList<String>();

    // Select All Query
    String selectQuery = "SELECT title FROM " + TABLE_PAYMENT;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            labels.add(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("title")));
        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }

    // closing connection and cursor
    c.close();
    db.close();

    // returning lables
    return labels;
}
```

And replace strings from database with resource strings and put into spinner:

```
 List<String> list = db.getAllInList();
    for(int i=0; i<list.size();i++ )
    {            
list.set(i,getResources().getStringArray(R.array.spinner_items)[i]);
    }
```